# Undo dynamic input

Tags: dynamic

Here is a simplified example of the problem.

```
DynamicModule[{customControl, eq, x, y, z},
 eq[] := Quiet@Solve[x + y + z == 10];
 customControl[{var_, init_, lbl_}] := 
  Column[{Row[{lbl, Button["Clear", Unset[var]]}], 
    Control[{{var, init}, 
      InputField[
        Dynamic[var, (var = #; (eq[] /. (lhs_ -> rhs_Integer) :> 
              Set[lhs, rhs])) &], Number, FieldSize -> 6] &}]}, 
   Alignment -> Center];
 Framed@Row@{customControl[{x, x, "x"}], customControl[{y, y, "y"}], 
    customControl[{z, z, "z"}], Spacer[50], 
    Dynamic[Column@{x, y, z}]}]
```

This piece of code solves the equation $x+y+z=10$ with $x$, $y$ and $z$ entered using `InputField`. For instance, when you enter $1$ for $x$, $2$ for $y$, $z$ is automatically set equal to $7$. Now how do you undo the last operation? Something like Ctrl+Z for dynamic input to `Unset` the value of $y$ AND the value of $z$?

When you `Unset` the value of y (by clicking the button), z is still equal to 7.

Comment: It may be better for your functions to return substitution rules with the values of x, y, z that you can apply wherever you need them without having to set actual values to those variables. That way, x, y, z never would have values, and you would not need to `Unset` them.

Comment: @MarcoB I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: This may be a case of an oversimplified minimal example, so perhaps this may not work in your actual problem, but I was thinking along the lines of the following: `Manipulate[
 Row[{"z == ", z /. First@Solve[x + y + z == 10, z]}],
 {{x, 1}, InputField},
 {{y, 1}, InputField}
 ]`. Here `z` never has a value assigned to it, so you never need to clear it.

Comment: @MarcoB I'll think about it. Thanks for the suggestion! Also, I'll need the output to be in the same `InputField`.